# CiviEvent: archive and duperules

Tags: civievent

we want to use CiviEvents, but there are still two big problems:

1. Past events are not shown. Is there any kind of archive that can be switched on?
2. Every entry of a participant will overwrite the data in the contact fields. How can we provide this? What kind of duperules should we use?

Does anybody can help?

Thanks und kind regards,
Regina

*CiviCRM 5.49.5. | WordPress 6.0.2 | German NGO*

Comment: Hi Regina - welcome to SE! For point 1 - do you mean events are not shown in the front end or for administrators in the backend?

Comment: Both. Mainly I want to administrate them in the backend. I tried to use
/civicrm/event/ical?reset=1&list=1&html=1&start=20220101&end=20220901
for the frontend, but it didn't show an event.
Thanks for help, Rebecca.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Events - Manage Events, you can search by date range to find old events (or all events if you don't enter a date range). I don't think there is a publicly-accessible view of past events out of the box, but you could do something with Drupal CiviCRM Entity, for example.

Usually, first name, last name and email is a good conservative dedupe rule to use that will avoid any overwriting of contact details.